# adding image namespace in svg through JS still doesn't show me the picture

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, client-side, client-side-scripting

after working out getting the parameter through a scaled version of a picture, I am trying through Javascript adding the picture with the original size parameter in SVG.

Firebug shows me the element, and all the necessary parameter, but with best wishes I am not getting through.

```
this.svg = document.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');     
var bild = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
var BildURL = this.image[0][0].getAttribute('xlink:href');
var imgX = new Image();
imgX.src = BildURL;

bild.setAttribute("x","60");
bild.setAttribute("y","40");
bild.setAttribute("width",imgX.width);
bild.setAttribute("height",imgX.height);    
bild.setAttribute("id","image12976");
bild.setAttribute("xlink:href",BildURL);
this.svg[0].appendChild(bild);
```

If i take a look in Firebug, the element fully exists.

```
<image id="image12976" x="60" y="40" width="300" height="430" xlink:href="img/Akira1.jpg">
```

I moved the mouse over the sceen, I see the rectangle of the picture in "investing mode", but not the content.

Can somebody here tell me what I did wrong?!

I would kindly thank you.

Tamer

Answer (score 15):

You should never use getAttribute/setAttribute on attributes that have prefixes, see [DOM 3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Namespaces-Considerations) for more details on why.

It will work just fine if you use

`getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href')`

and

`setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', your_url_here)`.

Comment: exactly that was it..... !!!! Yesterday I figured that out either.

But thank you very much!

Comment: Wrong. `getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href')` doesn't work. `getAttribute("xlink:href")` works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagNameNS

Comment: @Green: please back that up with an example. Mixing namespaced attributes with non-namespace-aware DOM methods is not advisable.

Comment: @ErikDahlström, please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422668/getting-xlinkhref-attribute-of-the-svg-image-element-dynamically-using-js-i

Comment: It's one of those DOM gotchas, in getAttributeNS the attribute mustn't have the prefix (xlink:href), but in setAttributeNS it should (for serialization). I've updated the answer (and it works in all browsers including chrome See http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-ElGetAttrNS.

Comment: @SmileMZ, why don't you accept the answer, if it solved your issue

Answer (score -3):

Try creating the image with `null` namespace:

```
var bild = document.createElementNS(null, 'image');
```