# Getting 'xlink:href' attribute of the SVG <image> element dynamically using JS in HTML DOM

Tags: dom, svg, xlink

I have a construction:

```
<div id="div">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg">
        <image x="2cm" y="2cm" width="5cm" height="5cm" id="img" xlink:href="pic.jpg"></image>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I want to get `pic.jpg` url and I need to begin from the most outer div, not exactly from the source `<image>` element:

```
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var svg = div.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')[0];
var img = svg.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image')[0];
var url = img.getAttribute('xlink:href');   // Please pay attention I do not use getAttributeNS(), just usual getAttribute()

alert(url);     // pic.jpg, works fine
```

My question is what is the right way to get such kind of attributes from element like SVG and its children?

Because before I tried to do this way and it also worked fine in Chrome (I didn't try other browsers):

```
var svg = div.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];   // I do not use NS
var img = svg.getElementsByTagName('image')[0];
var url = img.getAttribute('xlink:href');  // and do not use getAttributeNS() here too

alert(url);     // pic.jpg, works fine
```

But when I tried to use `getAttributeNS()` I got blank result:

```
var svg = div.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')[0];
var img = svg.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image')[0];

// Please pay attention I do use getAttributeNS()
var url = img.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href'); 

alert(url);     // but I got black result, empty alert window
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The correct usage is `getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href');`

Comment: Thanks!  This answer helped me *set* the xlink:href attribute of an image in my SVG content via JavaScript.  My code looks like: img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', 'new.url'); where new.url is the url of the image with which I want to replace the original.

Comment: Using jquery with SVG will cause you much pain and is best avoided.