# get xlink:href using javascript (in browser)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an element (in html)

```
 <image xlink:url="https://abc" id="my_ele">
```

I do

```
ele = document.getElementById("my_ele")
// Now want to get https://abc
```

This answer here [Getting 'xlink:href' attribute of the SVG <image> element dynamically using JS in HTML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422668/getting-xlinkhref-attribute-of-the-svg-image-element-dynamically-using-js-i)

says:

```
getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href');
```

But I'm not really sure what that translates to in my example.

(btw, Google docs displays images like this, at least in Chrome. Don't know why they don't use a proper IMG tag.)

Comment: change href to url in your example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<image xlink:href="https://abc" id="my_ele">
```

and

```
ele = document.getElementById("my_ele")
var url = ele.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href');
```

Comment: Thanks! Very weird with that w3 url, but OK.

Comment: (It doesn't allow me to mark them correct right away. There is always a waiting period.)