# Unable to get SVG 'use' to work, if created dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg

SVG has a wonderful `symbol` / `use` system where one can define e.g. icons just one, then drop them around the SVG by using `use`. Only I don't get it to work from JavaScript.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmdesignhki/tby6t3z8/).

The programmatically created `use` nodes become visible in the browser's DOM, and are identical to the statically created ones. But only the static ones are visible.

Can you explain what's going on?

---

`symbol` is very similar to `defs`, but allows the `viewBox` to be defined next to the symbol, thus making scaling of the entries easier and causes cleaner code. I'm okay working with `defs` but I faced similar issues there, too.

Note: My JavaScript is on the HTML side, not within SVG. I would like to have it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your fiddle (xref vs href) :

```
use.setAttributeNS( xlinkns, "xlink:xref","#tri");
```

intead of

```
use.setAttributeNS( xlinkns, "xlink:href","#tri");
```

Comment: Actually I think it should be `use.setAttributeNS( xlinkns, "href","#tri");`

Comment: Okay. Do you have a reference for why 'xlink:' can be dropped (surely because it is in the namespace parameter). My code was based on http://metaskills.net/2014/08/29/dynamic-svgs-using-defs-elements-and-javascript/ and he seems to say it repeatedly.

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12423019/3702797 Since @Robert Longson is a reference by himself