# SVG get parent of an <image> referenced by <use>

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an `<svg>` element which contains some `<image>` elements under `<defs>` tag, which are referenced by some `<use>` elements, like this:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ...>
      <defs>
        <image height="100%" id="test" width="100%" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,..."/>
      </defs>
      <g transform="translate(111,222)">
        <svg height="100" width="200" x="0" y="0">
          <use xlink:href="#test"/>
        </svg>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

I have a javascript function which iterates through the svg element, and at a certain point I get the image which is referenced by `<use>`.
What I want to do is to get the height/width of the `<svg>` above `<use>` from the `<image>` element.

If a try:

```
image.parentElement
```

I get the `<defs>` element, not the `<use>` element.

How can I find the element which referenced the image?
I can try to search the element which contains `xlink:href="#test"` , but is there a direct way to get this from the referenced `<image>` ?

Sorry for the noob question, but I'm new to javascript/html.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: [Getting 'xlink:href' attribute of the SVG <image> element dynamically using JS in HTML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422668/getting-xlinkhref-attribute-of-the-svg-image-element-dynamically-using-js-i/12423019#12423019)

Answer (score 0):

No. There is not a way to get the `<use>` element directly from the `<image>` element.