# SVG xlink:href with or without NS

Tags: svg, xlink

Currently I am working on a project which involves the dynamic creation of the SVGs <use />-Element. I am using jQuery, but struck the problem that .attr() does not work for setting the xlink:href-Attribute, since this requires setAttributeNS()
Now I also want to read the attribute (for the reason that I want to remove the belonging symbol), but this does not work with getAttributeNS, instead, .attr() (with getAttribute() under the hood) just works fine.

Why does that happen? This is really a strange behaviour, and totally confusing to me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6902768/109374 (short story: set/getAttribute don't support namespace prefixes)

Comment: Ok, I see, but that is definitely a strange behaviour..