# Creating SVG elements dynamically with javascript inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to create a rectangle inside an HTML page, then write some text on that rectangle. I also need that text to be a hyperlink. This is what I did but it is not working:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

    var svg   = document.documentElement;
    var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;

    var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'rect');
    rect.setAttribute('x',5);
    rect.setAttribute('y',5);
    rect.setAttribute('width',500);
    rect.setAttribute('height',500);
    rect.setAttribute('fill','#95B3D7');
    svg.appendChild(rect);
    document.body.appendChild(svg);

    var h=document.createElement('a');
    var t=document.createTextNode('Hello World');
    h.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(h);


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you help please? 
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create SVG tag with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215021/create-svg-tag-with-javascript)

Comment: OP, you're supposed to accept an answer or explain what's missing.

Comment: Please see the comment of @DenysSéguret 
https://www.google.com/search?q=stackexchange+how+to+accept+an+answer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Change

```
var svg   = document.documentElement;
```

to

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
```

so that you create a `SVG` element.

For the link to be an hyperlink, simply add a `href` attribute :

```
h.setAttributeNS(null, 'href', 'http://www.google.com');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/Udeyaje/2/)

Comment: Ok I will. The text works, but I want to change its position. I want it to be displayed on the rectangle like in the middle of the rect for example.

Comment: Note that the link is an html anchor tag, if you want it to be inside the svg you need to create an <svg:text> element (in the svg namespace), and an <svg:a> element, and then append these to the svg. See e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132443/dynamic-creation-of-svg-links-in-javascript.

Answer (score 58):

To facilitate svg editing you can use an intermediate function:

```js
function getNode(n, v) {
  n = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", n);
  for (var p in v)
    n.setAttributeNS(null, p, v[p]);
  return n
}
```

Now you can write:

```js
svg.appendChild( getNode('rect', { width:200, height:20, fill:'#ff0000' }) );
```

Example (with an improved getNode function allowing camelcase for property with dash, eg strokeWidth > stroke-width):

```js
function getNode(n, v) {
  n = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", n);
  for (var p in v)
    n.setAttributeNS(null, p.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(m, p, o, s) { return "-" + m.toLowerCase(); }), v[p]);
  return n
}

var svg = getNode("svg");
document.body.appendChild(svg);

var r = getNode('rect', { x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 20, fill:'#ff00ff' });
svg.appendChild(r);

var r = getNode('rect', { x: 20, y: 40, width: 100, height: 40, rx: 8, ry: 8, fill: 'pink', stroke:'purple', strokeWidth:7 });
svg.appendChild(r);
```

Comment: Notice that the "camelcase to dash feature" screws things up for you if you try to set the attribute "viewBox".

Comment: you're right, we should handle some exception to make it works well

Comment: @chris we can just write `"stroke-width":2`, [tested it](https://jsfiddle.net/ht6phnt9/2/), works great. omit the `replace` before v[p] and use quotes in the attribute name if there is a dash in it. mixing unquoted simple attributes and quoted-dashed ones works too.

Answer (score 45):

Add this to html:

```
<svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
```

Try this function and adapt for you program:

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";  

function createCircle()
{
    var myCircle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle"); //to create a circle. for rectangle use "rectangle"
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"id","mycircle");
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",100);
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",100);
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"r",50);
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","black");
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","none");

    document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(myCircle);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Elements can easily be added using the fragment.

- [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)
- [Range.createContextualFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment)

### Example

```html
<input style="width:300px" type="text" placeholder="Input something to change the text." /><br>
<script>
const frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`
<svg width="250" height="250">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250" fill="#95B3D7"></rect>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" style="cursor: pointer" target="_blank">
    <text x="10" y="130" style="
      font-size: 48px;
      fill:#faff00;">
      Hello world</text>
  </a>
</svg>
      `)
      const textElem = frag.querySelector("text")
      document.querySelector("input").onchange = (e) => {
        textElem.textContent = e.target.value
      }
      document.body.append(frag)
</script>
```

Answer (score -5):

```js
function getNode(n, v) {
  n = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", n);
  for (var p in v)
    n.setAttributeNS(null, p.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(m, p, o, s) { return "-" + m.toLowerCase(); }), v[p]);
  return n
}

var svg = getNode("svg");
document.body.appendChild(svg);

var r = getNode('rect', { x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 20, fill:'#ff00ff' });
svg.appendChild(r);

var r = getNode('rect', { x: 20, y: 40, width: 100, height: 40, rx: 8, ry: 8, fill: 'pink', stroke:'purple', strokeWidth:7 });
svg.appendChild(r);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remove this answer . This got added incorrectly while Szin clicked on "Copy snippet to answer" button above on the page.