# Dynamically adding SVGs from a separate file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have my SVG definitions in a separate file.  I can embed them into the HTML like so:

```
<svg class="icon icon-close"><use xlink:href="/icons/symbol-defs.svg#icon-close"></use></svg>
```

How can I embed these icons from this separate file with javascript?

---

I have tried writing the SVG string to the DOM with the following:

```
var icon = '<svg class="icon icon-close"><use xlink:href="/icons/symbol-defs.svg#icon-close"></use></svg>';
$('#myDiv').append(icon);
```

But the icon does not appear.

I have looked at [answers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539196/creating-svg-elements-dynamically-with-javascript-inside-html), which tells me that SVG elements are different to normal DOM elements (as I need to use `.createElementNS`).  However as all my definitions are in this separate file, I don't want to have to duplicate the SVG definitions inside the javascript.

Is there a way of getting Javascript to read from my `symbol-defs.svg` file and create an SVG and place it dynamically into the DOM?

Comment: There are a lot of ways. Maybe you want to generate this markup with DOM manipulation APIs ? In this case, a few failed attempts could be a plus for your question. (Basically, you'll need `createElementNS` and `setAttributeNS` methods.)

Comment: using `img` tag? I don't understand the exact problem!

Comment: if i just write the `<svg ...><use xlink:...></use></svg>` string to the DOM, the icon doesnt appear - I would like to have the icon appear

Comment: Write it how? Where's the code you wrote to do that? Please add it to the question.

Comment: Is myDiv existent when you try to append the icon to it? Can you try console.log($("#myDiv").length) there? What is the result?

Comment: `#myDiv` exists - if i do `$('#myDiv').append('<h1>hi</h1>');` then that `H1` tag appears fine - the SVG does not however

Comment: @sabithpocker I have tried `<img src="/icons/symbol-defs.svg#icon-close">` but I just get a broken image.

Comment: @RobertLongson this is not a duplicate of that, as they are defining the SVGs in the javascript code itself. My SVG definitions are in the `symbol-defs.svg` file - how do I take the definitions from that file and add it to the DOM with javascript?

Comment: You use something other than jquery to do it as per the duplicate and its answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson that question and none of the answers deal with a situation where there is an equivalent of the `<use>` tag inside the `<svg>` tag - unless I am missing something can you point me in the direction of a question or answer that is the same as my situation? My SVGs are not defined in the HTML, they are defined in a separate file (hence the title of my question), and I want to write these into the DOM with Javascript? Sorry if I am not explaining myself well here, but I am certain this is not a duplicate of that question

Comment: According to your question you are calling $('#myDiv').append(icon); This does not work. It does not matter where the data is coming from, you cannot use .append with svg elements. If it's not a duplicate please explain what you are using instead of jquery's append.