# Internet Explorer 11 - Dynamic SVG creation

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, internet-explorer-11, dom-manipulation

I need to create a JavaScript Framework to build a FlowChart inside the browser.
To manipulate the DOM I use mostly follow function `insertAdjacentHTML`.

Now I try my current implementation in different browser and I had to realize, that the Internet Explorer 11 can't use the `insertAdjacentHTML` function inside a SVGElement.

So I tried to add the new Elements on another ways.

- innerHTML (+=)
- appendChild

But nothing of them is in a SVGElement supported.
I have to add new elements inside my existing SVGElement (like a rectangle).
Does anyone have an idear how to relize that for the Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539196/creating-svg-elements-dynamically-with-javascript-inside-html

Comment: Oh God I overlooked this post. Looks really good, thanks. I want to try soon.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry, I overlooked a old post with the same question:
[Creating SVG elements dynamically with javascript inside HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539196/creating-svg-elements-dynamically-with-javascript-inside-html)

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect")
rect.setAttribute("fill", "black")
```

That are the magic words!